# 'BasicLSTMCell' object has no attribute '_kernel' when using tensorflow1.8.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.4

I installed tensorflow 1.8.0 with python 3.4 on windows using virtualenv.
I run the scripts:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units = 128)
print(lstm_cell.state_size)
inputs = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=(32,100))
h0 = lstm_cell.zero_state(32,np.float32)
output, h1 = lstm_cell.call(inputs, h0)
print(h1.h)
print(h1.c)
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/documents/Projects/Tensorflow-Learning/RNN/usingRNNCell.py", line 8, in <module>
    output, h1 = lstm_cell.call(inputs, h0)
  File "D:\dev_software\project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 620, in call
    array_ops.concat([inputs, h], 1), self._kernel)
AttributeError: 'BasicLSTMCell' object has no attribute '_kernel'
```

Did the API changed in high-version of tensorflow? Have anyone ever faced this?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `__call__` function instead of `call`, i.e., line `output, h1 = lstm_cell.call(inputs, h0)` can be rewritten as `output, h1 = lstm_cell(inputs, h0)`.

You can find more examples in tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent).